# Auth0 Login ServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, auth0

I follow up this tutorial using Laravel 5.4 [Creating your first Laravel app and adding authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-laravel-app-and-adding-authentication/)

But I can't  retrieve Auth0 users, the registration works fine in my dashboard new users are created in Auth0 server, but not in my local database and also  I can't  `dd(Auth0::getUser());`

I get this error:

> Class 'Auth0\Login\LoginServiceProvider' not found

I've added this

```
Auth0\Login\LoginServiceProvider::class
```

in my provider array and

```
'Auth0' => Auth0\Login\Facade\Auth0::class
```

in my   aliases.

[image: This is my controller]
I did all steps on configuration from Auth0 docs: [Auth0 PHP (Laravel) SDK](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel)

I'm out off option now!

Comment: did you do **composer dump-autoload**?

Comment: Yes, did that all time but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figure it out now.

The error was coming from 'AppServiceProvider.php'

Just import those two classes in AppServiceProvider.php  as:

```
use Auth0\Login\Contract\Auth0UserRepository as Auth0UserRepositoryContract; 
use Auth0\Login\Repository\Auth0UserRepository as Auth0UserRepository;
```

And then your Register method should look like this:

```
public function register()
{
   $this->app->bind( Auth0UserRepositoryContract::class, Auth0UserRepository::class ); 
   $this->app->bind( Auth0UserRepositoryContract::class, Auth0UserRepository::class ); 
}
```

if you want to persist data in your database then Create your own Repository and update the bind method `YourCustomerRepositoryContract::class, YourCustomerRepository::class`
Just like that.

For more info about creating your own Repository
[Auth0 PHP (Laravel) SDK Quickstarts: Login](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/01-login)