# Class "Auth0\Login\LoginServiceProvider" not found

Tags: laravel, auth0

I use as a reference that [Try using Auth0 with PHP (Laravel)](https://dev-classmethod-jp.translate.goog/articles/try-using-auth0-with-php-laravel/?_x_tr_sl=ja&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=ja&_x_tr_pto=wapp&_x_tr_hist=true).

When I use the command that "php artisan serve", an error that "Class "Auth0\Login\LoginServiceProvider" not found" happens.

This is the result of command.

```
PS C:\Users\…\Gebet_web> composer require auth0/login
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update auth0/login
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)      
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In ProviderRepository.php line 206:

  Class "Auth0\Login\LoginServiceProvider" not found


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: A similar question to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448739/auth0-login-serviceprovider

Comment: [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448739/auth0-login-serviceprovider?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hi, I'm a one of his friends and I hack with him. We tried that way but it failed. We tried to delete node_module and vendors.